# How to highlight syntax while on offline status?

Tags: javascript, html, highlight.js

I'm trying to make local code editor **github-dark** theme based with **highlight.js** library. But when importing from local file (literally copied source code on https://unpkg.com/highlighted-code@0.3.7/min.js) and stored it on `min.js` file.

This is the `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    textarea[is="highlighted-code"] {
      padding: 18px;
      width: 1200px;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="module">
    (async ({ chrome, netscape }) => {

      const { default: HighlightedCode } =
      await import('min.js');

      HighlightedCode.useTheme('github-dark');
    })(self);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea is="highlighted-code" cols="80" rows="12" language="javascript" tab-size="2" auto-height>

</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```

Sadly, it is only working when I am connected to internet. I want to use it even I am not connected to internet.

Comment: I'm slightly surprised it works at all in that case, local imports have to be relative, they can't be bare like `min.js`. So it should be `await import("./min.js");`. But if that were the problem, I would expect it not to work even when online (unless there's a fallback of some kind).

Comment: I guess there's no way, I can use syntax highlight while I am offline.

Comment: I expect there is. If you watch the network panel, what requests are done when you're online that may not be being satisfied locally? For instance, are there requests for subordinate resources like grammars or stylesheets or...

Comment: Well... I'm getting a screen that shows something like documentation of it. But that's happening when I use the link. Using the unpacked one doesn't work. I don't know where I am doing wrong.